# Changing name attribute using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I've got a jQuery function that attempts to change the `id`, `name` and `class` attribute values of an element.

The `id` and `class` change seems to work but for some curious reason, trying to change the `name` of the element never works.

Here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$("table select").live("change", function () {

    var id = $(this).attr('id');

    if ($(this).attr('classname') != "selected") {
        var rowIndex = $(this).closest('tr').prevAll().length;
        $.getJSON("/Category/GetSubCategories/" + $(this).val(), function (data) {
            if (data.length > 0) {

                $("#" + id).attr('classname', 'selected');
                $("#" + id).attr('id', 'sel' + rowIndex);
                $("#" + id).attr('name', 'sel' + rowIndex); // this never works

                var position = ($('table').get(0));

                var tr = position.insertRow(rowIndex + 1);
                var td1 = tr.insertCell(-1);
                var td2 = tr.insertCell(-1);
                td1.appendChild(document.createTextNode('SubCategory'));
                var sel = document.createElement("select");
                sel.name = 'parent_id';

                sel.id = 'parent_id';

                sel.setAttribute('class', 'unselected');
                td2.appendChild(sel);

                $.each(data, function (GetSubCatergories, Category) {
                    $('#parent_id').append($("<option></option>").
       attr("value", Category.category_id).
       text(Category.name));
                });
            }

        });

    }
});
});
```

Answer (score 66, accepted):

The `name` cannot be changed because once you have modified the `id`, the selector in the subsequent expression (which uses the *unmodified* id) is selecting nothing :)

```
$("#" + id).attr('id', 'sel' + rowIndex);
$("#" + id).attr('name', 'sel' + rowIndex); // this can't ever work
```

Try chaining them together like this, to keep the reference to the current selection:

```
$("#" + id).attr('id', 'sel' + rowIndex)
           .attr('name', 'sel' + rowIndex);
```

Alternatively, reorder the statements such that you change the name (and/or whatever else) *before* changing the id:

```
$("#" + id).attr('name', 'sel' + rowIndex);
$("#" + id).attr('id', 'sel' + rowIndex);
```

You can also assign the selection to a variable:

```
var $el = $("#" + id);
$el.attr("id", 'sel' + rowIndex);
...
```

Comment: chaining just returns the element, no? You may have to re-arrange the order, good catch btw!

Comment: My answer missed the obvious completely! But jQuery has a `name()` function? Must be a typo. Also, worth noting that it is probably better to call `attr()` once, and pass in a object with all the settings.

Comment: Thought maybe you had some insider info!

Comment: Duh of course guys, Thanks a lot, I think its time for me to go home now before I ask any more stupid questions :)

Answer (score 4):

Instead of chaining you can pass into `.attr()`

```
{
    "id" : "sel" + rowIndex ,
    "name" : "sel" + rowIndex
}
```

A lot of jQuery functions accept objects like above when you have to pass in (string comma string) data like `.css()` and `.animate()`

Answer (score 3):

Karim is right,

```
$("#" + id).attr('classname', 'selected');
$("#" + id).attr('id', 'sel' + rowIndex);
$("#" + id).attr('name', 'sel' + rowIndex);
```

could be changed to

```
$("#" + id).attr('name', 'sel' + rowIndex);
$("#" + id).attr('classname', 'selected');
$("#" + id).attr('id', 'sel' + rowIndex);
```

to change the name first, $("#" + id) is the same as getElementById and once you change the id, its no longer the element you meant to refer to

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue where I needed to reassign those attributes. I managed to achieve this simply and only by using the native method setAttribute().

```
$('.check-box-id').each(function (index,element) {
    element.setAttribute("id" , 'ingredients'+index+'.id');
    element.setAttribute("name" , 'ingredients['+index+'].id');
   
})
```