# Change name input by jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want get of name old input `(Input 1)` and add it with a change to new name input `(Input 2)`.

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/F8SLR/

EX : i have this name: `typeservice[]` and i get it and change to: `typeservice_un[]`

I try as:

html:

```
<input type="text" name="typeservice[]" value="Input 1" id="000">
<input type="submit" value="CLICK ME" class="Chng">
    <br>
<input type="text" name="" value="Input 2" id="111">
```

js:

```
$(document).on('click','.Chng', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var name = $('#000').attr('name');
    alert(name+'_un[]')
    //$('#111').attr('name',name+'_un[]');
})
```

What do i do?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Jquery change name attribute](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2715260/jquery-change-name-attribute)

Comment: also, IDs must not start with a number.

Comment: so you think you wont be downvoted just for putting the pic a model? lol a bad question is a bad question dude

Comment: The code you have appears to work. What issue are you seeing?

Comment: Well everything seems fine if you remove comment works on your fiddle. Make sure to change id. It must not start with number and that can give error on some browser.

Comment: The problem is his new name is `typeservice[]_un[]` instead of `typeservice_un[]`.

Comment: @NicoO - IDs can start with a number in HTML5.

Comment: @j08691 you are right, but it must contain at least one character

Comment: `$('#000').attr('name').replace('[]','_un[]');` will work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've changed the following line in your fiddle:

`var name = $('#abc').attr('name').split('[]').join('');`

Basically you have to remove the brackets from the end of the line then append your new text. Also, I've also changed your ids to letters instead of numbers as this is best practice.

### DEMO