# Modify a form button using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a button that looks like the following:

```
<button type="submit" class="desktop-button tiny" onclick="document.stacks_in_3151032_page6.formAction.value = 'login';">LOGIN</button>
```

I am unable to modify the code of the button so I want to know if I can add a name to the button using jQuery or JavaScript? I want the button to look like the following:

```
<button type="submit" class="desktop-button tiny" name="login_button" onclick="document.stacks_in_3151032_page6.formAction.value = 'login';">LOGIN</button>
```

Comment: You can use `attr('name', 'login_button');` to do what you need, however this sounds like an XY question. What is the issue you're trying to solve by adding the `name` attribute?

Comment: Not name, use id. `id="login-button"`.

Comment: Quite easy. `document.querySelector(???).setAttribute('name', 'login_button')'`. But for best answer you need to provide more details. You don't want to select this button by very generic class `.tiny`. So in order to locate button reliably, you need to base selector on HTML structure.

Comment: It's a login "stack" that I can't edit and I want to be able to write the last login date and time to the DB. The way I am thinking of doing this is to use if (isset($_POST['login_button']))  and then update the DB with the date and time.

Comment: When user logins, it must check his credential in server, So why you dont save the time of login in server? I mean you do not need to send login time from client to server.

Comment: Here is already a nice answer posted in stackoverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2715260/jquery-change-name-attribute

Comment: Already answered here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2715260/jquery-change-name-attribute

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jquery change name attribute](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2715260/jquery-change-name-attribute)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this using:

jQuery:

```
$('.desktop-button.tiny').attr('name', 'login_button');
```

Or Javascript:

```
document.querySelector(".desktop-button.tiny").setAttribute("name", "login_button");
```

```js
var addNameAttr = function () {
  $('.desktop-button.tiny').attr('name', 'login_button');
  console.log($('.desktop-button.tiny').attr('name'));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="submit" class="desktop-button tiny" onclick="addNameAttr()">LOGIN</button>
```

Comment: Thanks but I am not able to amend the button code to add the id.

Comment: I've edited the answer, you can use the class instead of adding an id

Comment: Great - I am very much a newbie with jQuery and Javascript. Do I need to add some sort of onLoad type code to make the above work?

Comment: Just load your `javascript` file in your HTML using the `<script>` tag. If you want to use jQuery as well, you need to add `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>` like I did in the snippet.

Answer (score 0):

You can select the button using its classes, `.desktop-button .tiny`.

Together with setting the name attribute, this would result in:

jQuery:

```
$(".desktop-button.tiny").attr("name", "login_button");
```

Pure JavaScript:

```
document.querySelector(".desktop-button.tiny").setAttribute("name", "login_button");
```

Answer (score 0):

You first need to obtain the element and then set the name attribute.

Without jquery this would be:

```
<button id='my-button' type="submit" class="desktop-button tiny" onclick="document.stacks_in_3151032_page6.formAction.value = 1'login';">LOGIN</button>

document.getElementById('my-button').setAttribute('name', 'login_button');
```

With jquery, you would be able to find the element without adding an id as such:

```
$('button.desktop-button.tiny').attr('name', 'login_button');
```

Hope this helps.